# How can I create conditional test cases using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, typescript, automated-tests, protractor

Currently, I have some test cases that I only want to execute in certain conditions.

```
it ('user is able to log in', function() {
   if(siteAllowsLogin) {
       .....
   }
```

Using the above syntax results in sitesNotAllowingLogin to PASS this test. I know there is a solution to mark the test as PENDING, but I would rather the test did not show, if it was not applicable.

I also want to keep the logic inside of the test case, if possible. So keeping the if block inside the test case.

Any suggestions on how to skip this test if the condition is not met so that it does not display on the results as PENDING or PASSED.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not.  It's exactly like you said - you can make it fail/pending/pass.  But you would have to move the `if (condition)` statement outside of the `it` block, which I know is exactly what you said you don't want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - it does seem like the best solution.  However, I want to see if there are other ideas before pushing for this solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `ignore` function in front to suppress the test if the provided predicate/state is true:

```
var ignore = function(exp){return{it:((typeof exp==='function')?exp():exp)?function(){}:it}};

describe('Suite 1', function() {

    it("test a", function() {
        expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });

    ignore(true).it("test b", function() {
        expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });

    ignore(skip).it("test c", function() {
        expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });

    function skip(){
      return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this would be a good solution.  I've tried to implement it, but I get a 'ReferenceError: ignore is not defined'.  I'm using TypeScript to write my tests - can it be used in TypeScript?

Comment: I'm curious where `ignore` is coming from too.  I get the same error as @fuzzii on that.

Comment: @fuzzii @Gunderson, the `ignore` is from the 'selenium-webdriver/testing' extension. Unfortunately it works only with Protractor/Mocha. I've added the declaration so it can work with Protractor/Jasmine.