# Executing e2e test in angular based on configuration

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I am working on a project on Angular7 where `e2e` tests are written using protractor.

I have made a new feature in my project which I want to control via a functional switch. When switch is `ON` feature will be rendered to user and hidden when switch is `OFF`.

Switch will be a boolean value in my `app.conf.json` file. This will be read in `ts` file of component as a flag and flag will be used in html with `*ngIf` condition.

My question is, is there a way I can execute certain e2e tests based on reading the boolean value from my `app.conf.json` file. When value is true e2e test related to new feature are run and not run when it is false. I tried searching this on internet but no luck.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748394/protractor-jasmine-conditional-test-cases) helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use if statement outside your 'it' spec and read your condition from json file.
example :

```
 var cnd = require('./test.json');
if(cnd.condition){

  it('should do something', () => {

  });}
```

test.json:

```
[{"condition":"true"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place it in your browser params:

```
exports.config = {
   //...
   params: {
     myProjectConfig: require('path/to/project/config')
   }
}
```

Then call it in your code:

```
const isFeatureOn = browser.params.myProjectConfig.toggleFeature;
if (isFeatureOn) {
   //...
}
//...
```